# Personalizando o Scroll de uma 'div'

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Como há muitas resoluções de vários dispositivos diferentes, estou com uma dificuldade de exibir uma lista de feed. Segue uma imagem de como eu acho melhor de exibir tal `DIV` (lista), em vista que a página é responsiva e não é trivial pôr uma `scroll-bar` num dispositivo móvel.

[image: container-feed]

Correção da imagem: Scroll Buttom**

Comment: E você quer um script que faça isso certo? em javascript simples ou pode ser com jQUery ou Mootools? Já tentou algum código? dá para dar um exemplo do seu HTML?

Comment: Tentei fazer só com o CSS. Com certeza não fui bem sucedido rsr. Pode ser JQuery sim! *u*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui fica um exemplo feito à mão:

```
$('div.img img').on('click', function () {
    var scrollDIV = $('#scrollDIV');
    var scrollAtual = scrollDIV.scrollTop();
    var novoScroll = scrollAtual + ($(this).hasClass('up') ? -200 : 200);
        scrollDIV.animate({
            scrollTop: novoScroll + 'px'
        }, 1500);
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/GbsY5/2/)

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é que você faça uso de alguma biblioteca, desenvolver alguma não seria tão complicado, porém, já existem inúmeras disponíveis no mercado.

Minha dica para você seria usar o [vertical jquery carousel](http://amazingcarousel.com/examples/vertical-jquery-carousel-id10)