# Efeito do site da Apple

Tags: jquery

gostaria de saber como se chama esse efeito do site da Apple, de quando o usuário da scroll, ele pula pra seção seguinte.

[Clique aqui para ver o efeito.](https://www.apple.com/br/iphone-5s/)

Comment: Deixei uma resposta com uma solução jQuery, o site da apple não usa jQuery. Vi que nunca aceitou uma das suas perguntas antigas como aceite. É simpático e útil marcar a melhor resposta como certa, assim quem respondeu é também recompensado. Claro que é bom esperar antes de aceitar para dar espaço a novas (e talvez melhores respostas) mas não esqueça de aceitar a resposta.

Comment: não tinha "reputação" suficiente para marcar como resposta certa, precisa de 15+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa animação não é dificil mas tem de ter em conta a [direção da roda do mouse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25220/129) e um menu vertical que faz [scroll suave](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7391/129) usando o animate e scrollTop para ancoras ou elementos na página.

**O menu da apple:**

```
<nav id="progress-nav" class="placeholder on light" style="opacity: 1;">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-scene="hero" class="hero progress-nav-trigger"><span class="dot"></span><span class="hover-text">Início</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-scene="forward" class="forward dark progress-nav-trigger active"><span class="dot"></span><span class="hover-text">Design</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-scene="smart" class="smart progress-nav-trigger"><span class="dot"></span><span class="hover-text" style="right: 47px;">Características</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-scene="ios" class="ios progress-nav-trigger"><span class="dot"></span><span class="hover-text">iOS 7</span></a></li>
        <li><a data-scene="cases" class="cases progress-nav-trigger"><span class="dot"></span><span class="hover-text">Capa</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Note que cada `li` tem um campo `data-`, por exemplo `data-scene="ios"` e vendo no corpo da página há um elemento exatamente com esse `ID`...

```
<section id="ios" class="... etc
```

Ora tendo esta estrutura o JavaScript/jQuery para fazer a animação pode ser:

### função que faz o scroll animado

```
function fazerScroll(pos) {
    $(document.body).animate({
        scrollTop: pos
    }, 1000);
}
```

### parte do mousewheel

```
$(document).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var evento = e.originalEvent;
    var roda = (evento.wheelDelta) ? evento.wheelDelta : -(evento.detail || evento.deltaY);
    roda < 0 ? posicao.atual++ : posicao.atual--;
    if (posicao.atual < 0) posicao.atual = 0;
    if (posicao.atual > posicao.total) posicao.atual = posicao.total;
    fazerScroll(posicao.elementos[posicao.atual]);
});
```

### parte do click no menu

```
$('#progress-nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idDestino = $(this).data('scene');
    var posicaoDestino = $('#' + idDestino).position().top;
    fazerScroll(posicaoDestino);
});
```

## Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/w86L5/